# Advice on setting up new TreeView Data Type

Tags: delphi, listview, treeview

I would like some advice and or tips on how to go about setting up a new Object Class for a TreeView using the TreeView's Node.Data property.

I know how to create a basic Object type that can write/read from the .Data property, I do something like this:

```
type
  TMyData = class(TComponent)
  private
    FString1: String;
    FString2: String;
    FInteger1: Integer;
  published
    property String1: String read FString1 write FString1;
    property String2: String read FString2 write FString2;
    property Integer1: Integer read FInteger1 write FInteger1;
  end;
```

**To write a value to one of the properties Node.Data property:**

```
TMyData(TreeView1.Selected.Data).String1:= 'save this String';
```

**To read a value:**

```
ShowMessage(TMyData(TreeView1.Selected.Data).String1);
```

Thats a pretty basic example of assigning Data to a Tree Node, Now this is where I need the help and advice, tips etc...

From my example above, you can easily read/write standard properties such as String, Integer, Boolean etc. What about including and reading/writing to and from say a TListBox or TListView?

Instead of writing standard data to a Tree Node, how about adding items to that TListView and writing the contents of that TListView to the TreeView Node.

What if when clicking on one of the Tree Nodes, instead of returning a string, it could populate that TListView with Items and Images that were saved to earlier.

**(1)** This is the main form where you can add the Nodes to the TreeView. I actually use a more enhanced function to add to my TreeView, like so:

```
function AddMyDataNode(ATreeView: TTreeView; NodeName: String; NodeImage: Integer;
    String1, String2: String; Integer1: Integer;
    SelectNode: Boolean): TTreeNode;
var
  Obj: TMyData;
  Node: TTreeNode;
begin
  Result:= nil;

  Obj:= TMyData.Create(nil);
  try
    Obj.String1:= String1;
    Obj.String2:= String2;
    Obj.Integer1:= Integer1;

    Node:= ATreeView.Items.AddObject(ATreeView.Selected, NodeName, Obj);
    Node.ImageIndex:= NodeImage;
    Node.SelectedIndex:= NodeImage;

    Result:= Node;

    if SelectNode then
      Node.Selected:= True;

    ATreeView.SetFocus;
  except on E: Exception do
    ShowMessage('Could not add MyData Node: ' + E.Message);
  end;
end;
```

Editing a Node will show another form called the Data Form...:

**(2)** This Data Form is where the data from the Node on the Main Form is read/written. With an addition of a TListView. The ListView should also be read/saved with the standard properties too.

Adding/Editing a ListView item may include other standard properties, such as:

**(3)** The values on this form are saved into the ListView data.

So in a nutshell:

- The TreeView Node.Data stores
  standard properties and also a
  TListView.
- This Data is show on another form
  called Data Form.
- The ListView on the Data Form also
  has data.
- Editing the ListView on the Data Form
  will show an additional Form with
  standard properties.

I would like to know how I could best approach this, what tips could you provide, what is the easiest way to achieve something like this etc?

Writing/Reading to and from the ListView is easily implemented I imagine in that it can be done by accessing the `ListView Items.Item[x].Data` property. Getting the ListView Data to store with the TreeView is the problem, I don't know how I could implement this type of behaviour.

I would like to know advice on things like how I could define the Types etc.

I look forward to hearing your ideas on this.

Comment: Your current approach whereby you put an object reference into the `Data` property will scale perfectly well.  You just need to keep adding to `TMyData`. Another option would be to subclass `TTreeNode` and make use of `TTreeView.OnCreateNodeClass`.

Comment: I am just confused how I can set/get ListView Data to work in harmony with the TreeView data. Each Tree Node when edited to show that Data Form will always have different ListView items. The standard properties are easy to do, the ListView is more tricky.

Comment: why is list view harder? I don't understand.

Comment: it shouldnt be, I edited my Question to make clearer on this perhaps the Question is not understood correctly. Because the ListView will use data too eg, Items.Item[x].Data for example, this ListView data must read/write into the TreeView Node.Data property too. I must be confusing myself or something because I see no easy answer.

Comment: I'm not sure why you don't just add a list view field to `TMyData` but I must admit your question is so long I glaze over each time I try to read it from top to bottom! Perhaps someone else has more stamina that me!!

Comment: You should of tried writing it, it took forever! Apologies for the long post anyway, I tried to get as much information in as possible. Basically, the Tree Nodes open the Data Form, the Data Form contains standard properties, it also contains a ListView. That ListView should also contain standard property data just like the TreeView does - BUT the ListView Data should also link to that Tree Node.Data - I hope that sounds more clearer.

Comment: PS, try the source demo I linked and give that a run, it may explain more better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your confusion is thinking of storing Visual Forms and components including their data. I believe you can do this with the the streaming system - although I never have! I like to keep the data and the visuals as separate as possible.

So you need a custom list to put in MyData that contains all the data and settings that need to go in the listview something like MyDataList: (I'm typing this straight in!)

```
type

TMyDataViewData = class(TPersistent)
  Caption: string;
  ImageIndex: Integer;
  StateIndex: Integer;
  Group: Integer;
  MemoData: TStrings;
end;

TMyDataViewDataList = class(TPersistent)
  TheList: TObjectList;
  property Items[Index:Integer]:MyDataViewData read getItems write SetItems;
  property Count: Integer read GetCount;
  . 
  .
  .
end;

  TMyData = class(TComponent)
  private
    FString1: String;
    FString2: String;
    FInteger1: Integer;
  private 
    MyForm: TMyEditform;
  published
    procedure Edit(Owner: TComponent);
    property String1: String read FString1 write FString1;
    property String2: String read FString2 write FString2;
    property Integer1: Integer read FInteger1 write FInteger1;
    property TheDataList: TMyDataViewDataList read fTheDataList write fTheDataList;  
end;

procedure TMyData.Edit;
var
  F: TMyEditForm;
begin
  F:= TMyEditForm.create(Owner);
  F.DataList := TheDatalist;  // data for listview and memos
  F.ShowModal;
  .
  .
  . 
end;
```

Then in your Treeview you only need to do:

```
  If TreeNode.Data is TMyData then
    TMyData(TreeNode.Data).Edit(Self);
```

After the edit all the data for changing the treeview node info should be in MyData
   so you can do

```
  Node.Text := TMyData(Node.Data).TheDataList.Items[0].Caption;
```

or

```
for i := 0 to TMyData(Node.data).TheDataList.Count do
    Node.AddChild(TMyData(Node.Data).TheDataList.Items[i].Caption);
```

You can also easily expose properties of the Datalist to TMyData directly :)

and such like. Probably a few syntax error in there!

Comment: Thanks for posting, I think you were right in that I was thinking of storing the actual Listview in there (because of the item images, caption etc). I will try this out thanks..

Comment: you write that you like to keep the gui as separate as possible from the data - which is a good practice. but in your code you do the opposite: the data class contains a form. 'editForm. Execute(myData)' would be much better imho.

Comment: @craig: note that if you have d2009 or higher, you do not need the custom list class wrapping TObjectList. Just use the generic TObjectList<T>.

Comment: @Smasher I am using XE, still learning about the Generics, I know it is in Generics.Collections but thats about it :)

Comment: @smasher - touche! - As I said I was typing it straight in (and keeping it as simple as possible). You are correct.

Comment: @Craig: there's nothing simpler than using the generic collection classes really. Just forget about all the casting stuff needed with the old classes and you will be able to use them.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any problems with your approach. You can let your data object contain a list of objects (I don't know why you inherit from `TComponent` in a class that has nothing to with visual components):

```
TMyData = class
private
  FString  : String;
  FInteger : Integer;
  FItems   : TList <TItem>   // where TItem is your custom object class
public
  // ... properties ...
end;
```

This list is then displayed in the list box:

```
 for Item in MyData.Items do
   ListBox.Items.AddObject (Item.ToString, Item);
```

If you edit one of the items, you do the same thing: get the object out of the list box's data and pass it on to the next form.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I derived it from TComponent as I thought if it involved ListView, I would need it. Thanks for the tip and code example, I will see if I can implement this...

Comment: You should not have a `TListView` in your data class (and you wouldn't need to derive from `TComponent` if you wished to do so). The list view belongs to the GUI and should be filled from something like a `TList`.

Comment: I realise that now with your guidance :) I am still very much learning Delphi and OOP on an intemeditate level.